# How to preserve code folding in emacs?

Tags: web-mode, code-folding

I am using `web-mode` to fold/unfold code. When I fold code, kill buffer and re open  it, code folding  disappears.

How to  preserve code folding even after killing  and  reopening buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried [Vimish fold](https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold), and it seems to do what you ask.  Below is my setup for the keybindings:

```lisp
(require 'vimish-fold)
(vimish-fold-global-mode 1)
;; this registers a region for future folding/unfolding
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") #'vimish-fold)
;; this unregisters the region under point from folding/unfolding
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") #'vimish-fold-delete)
;; this is the actual fold/unfold command
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") #'vimish-fold-toggle)
```

I think [Mark](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2487/mark) is the author of this mode, so, maybe he'll chime in and write something about it too.

Comment: vimish fold doesn't  preserve fold if  i restart  emacs,  do  you know any other  packages which does that?

Comment: @ChillarAnand did Emacs close in emergency, i.e. such that it wasn't able to run hooks on closing? I'm asking this because it looks like vimish-fold saves the folds information at the time Emacs closes. You may, however force it to by running `M-: (vimish-fold--kill-emacs-hook)`. But there are few other things about saving folds that I personally don't like: 1. huge file names for the files where folds info is recorded. 2. foldining info isn't recorded for killed buffers. I'll put an fr in the bug tracker for this.

Comment: There are also two other alternatives I know about, but neither of them saves folds between Emacs sessions: `org-struct` mode (allows you to use comments in other modes to embed Org-like headings which you can then collapse and expand) and `hide-show` minor mode, which is the basic folding, except it doesn't have the option to save the folding either.